# Copy System Settings from one CRM2011 server to another

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I need to copy the System Settings specified on one CRM2011 server onto another.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good tool to help in copying settings from one system to another system is the Configuration Migration Tool that ships in the Microsoft CRM 2013 and Microsoft CRM 2015 SDK (Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 SDK is available for download here - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40321 ).  When you extract the SDK files, this tool is in the Tools\ConfigurationMigration directory.  You can read up about it at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn647421(v=crm.6).aspx .  It includes the ability to copy not only the data, but also the schema for entities that contain settings or settings related data to copy between different CRM Servers or organizations.  You should be able to use this tool to connect to a CRM 2011 Server.  I've used it and it is a handy tool, but I think it's best suited for migration of settings and configuration related data.  If you need to migrate other data or large amounts of data, you'd be better off using something like the CozyRoc SSIS, the Kingsway SSIS, or Scribe Sofware's integration/migration tools since they have more flexibility in mapping the data, filtering options, and better performance.